# Manually play Page Refresh animation from code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

I have a `NavigationView` that manages navigation across several different `Frame` layouts in my application. This way a user can flip to another part of the application on a different navigation stack, and then come back to their original frame and be right where they left off.

I have setup each frame to play navigation animation like so:

```
<Frame x:Name="UserFrame">
    <Frame.ContentTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <NavigationThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Frame.ContentTransitions>
</Frame>
```

This creates a nice animation anytime something is added or removed from the frame's navigation stack. However, when I switch between active frames (simply by setting the visibility of the active frame to `visible` and the visibility of the inactive frames to `collapsed`) I do not get the same animation effect because no navigation actually occurred on the frames navigation stack.

[According to the documentation on NavigationThemTransition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.NavigationThemeTransition), the animation that is playing when I navigate is the `Page Refresh` animation. It states:

> Page refresh is the default animation for page navigation. It is a combination of a slide up animation and a fade in animation for the incoming content. You should use page refresh when you use top level navigation like a navigation menu.

Is there a way to call this pre-built animation from my code behind? If not, what would be the best way to create an animation, and make it accessible to each of my `Frame` layouts used for navigating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to call a pre-build transition, such as `NavigationThemeTransition` and expose for a situation that is not an actual *Frame Navigation*, but actually something entirely different like a toggle on the Frame's `Visibility`.

For that situation, you should utilize the static method `SetImplicitShowAnimation(UIElement, ICompositionAnimationBase)`, from the 
 `ElementCompositionPreview` Class.

As you can see, this static method exposes two argument, the `UIElement`, which takes the element that you want to animate, and the Animation which you can create with the `Compositor` defined in the `Windows.UI.Composition` namespace.

Useful links : [Create Custom Page Transitions](http://varunshandilya.com/create-custom-page-transitions-with-windows-creators-update/), [ElementCompositionPreview Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview)